# PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore() store nothing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm having trouble using `PlatformUI` to store my preferences. I wanted to create a PreferencesService to access and edit preferences in my plugin. I'm calling from my `Activator` an initialization function of my service however this has no impact. Here is my function :

```
public static void initPreferences() throws NullContributionException, CoreException {
    final IPreferenceStore store = PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore();
    for (String languageId : LanguageService.getLanguagesIds()) {
        store.setDefault(languageId, true);
        for (CheckerContainer checker : CheckerService.getCheckers(languageId)) {
            String checkerPreferenceId = getPreferencesId(languageId, checker.getId());
            store.setDefault(checkerPreferenceId, true);
            store.setDefault(checkerPreferenceId + PREF_SEVERITY_ATTRIBUTE, "Error");
        }
    }
    store.needsSaving();
}
```

I'm calling it from my activator this way :

```
@Override
public void start(final BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    // Initialize all preferences
    UserPreferencesService.initPreferences();

    Activator.context = bundleContext;
}
```

Both verification, using the debugger and veryfing `.metadata` prefs files indicate that theses modifications aren't taken in consideration by Eclipse.

Is it a bad practice ? I'm editing an old 3.4 Eclipse Plugin that was doing it kind of this way but I can't find the difference which fails my use of preferences.

Thank you for your reading, and maybe for your answers,
Waldo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is bad practise. This preference store is for the workbench only.

You should be using the `IPreferenceStore` specific to your plugin. If your activator extends `AbstractUIPlugin` you can get this be calling the `AbstractUIPlugin.getPreferenceStore` method.

To initialize defaults in your preference store you should use the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences` extension point to define an `initializer` class where you set the defaults.

Note: The `needsSaving` method just returns true or false to tell you if the preference store has been changed - it does not set that flag or do the save.

Also note that default values are not written to the preferences file.

Comment: Thank you greg ! You made it working !!! I also had to add a `getDefault()` method in my `Activator` so I could reach the static method `getPreferenceStore()`.